# Paypal check out links not showing in WHMCS

Tags: paypal, whmcs

Im trying to set up Paypal so I have the payment options on the right side of screen as what they show in the below picture
https://docs.whmcs.com/PayPal_Checkout_Migration_Guide
Right now all I have is the small radio button with the word "Paypal"  to place orders with
I went through every set up page and setting I can find with no luck
Here is my cart page
https://rshweb.com/clientarea/cart.php?a=view
My source code for the page shows it
div class="express-checkout-buttons"
But all I get is the wonderful green check out button

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as a link to your cart page.

Comment: This is the code that should show the Paypal links
<div class="express-checkout-buttons"></div>

Comment: Does any one know which Module WHMCS uses for the Paypal links?

My code:   

<div class="express-checkout-buttons"></div>

Should be trying to pull the information from someplace